# Git: create a link against a file

Tags: github

i am currently solving the problem of [projecteuler](http://projecteuler.net) and storing the source code on github in a repository https://github.com/amitshree/projecteuler . I am not writing the questions related to the source code but i want to see the question against the source code from github linking to projecteuler question. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: i'm at a loss at what you actualyl want to do. what have you tried? how did it fail?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/amitshree/projecteuler where problem1.java is a file which is a solution of a question which is given on projecteuler.net. i want to create a link on github in front of problem1.java through which a visitor can see the question

Comment: if you want to add a link in your README, check out markdown-syntax; if you want to add a link in your file-view, think again.

Comment: can i add a link to my commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i add a link to my commit

In [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown), that kind of link is called **references**:

> certain references are auto-linked:

```
* SHA: be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
* User@SHA ref: mojombo@be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
* User/Project@SHA: mojombo/god@be6a8cc1c1ecfe9489fb51e4869af15a13fc2cd2
* \#Num: #1
* User/#Num: mojombo#1
* User/Project#Num: mojombo/god#1
```